# Error retrieving cookie value in included page - PHP

Tags: php, session, cookies, include

I got a problem, I will explain myself with a representative escenario:

I have two php scripts/pages:

Test1.php:

```
<?php
include_once('test2.php');

session_start();
$id = session_id();

echo "my session id: " .$id.'<br>';
setcookie("SSID", $id);

test(); 
?>
```

Test2.php:

```
<?php

function test() {
echo "session id on test2 <br>";
echo $_COOKIE["SSID"];
}

?>
```

This is a representative piece of code of my problem, what I am trying to do is to store my session id in a cookie and retrieve it in the second page to resume my session. I know that this is not necessary. In my test server I dont need to do this, but in the production one this is necessari. I can't change any configuration of the production server so I have to adapt the code to the server's configuration.

My main problem here is that the second script gets the session id stored in the cookie the last time. An example:

1st time executing test1.php I get:

```
my session id: dg2mjk8ros8ajrj3n6i8oa4gj1
session id on test2 
vrulbnvvff23bpmm6qbbqbk960
```

2nd time executing test1.php:

```
my session id: cj17k0q08mhgpjn9gf0dt0n9i6
session id on test2 
dg2mjk8ros8ajrj3n6i8oa4gj1
```

as you can see the cookie value retrieved in the test2.php function is the last used, not the current. I'm stuck.

I would appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong with your code or most likely your server setup. You session_id shouldn't change, for some reason your web server is generating a new session every page load. This shouldn't happen it defeats the purpose of even having a session. Is there any other code running or is this it?

The reason your cookie is always the same as the previous value is because the `$_COOKIE` array is populated before your php code runs, it isn't changed if you create a new cookie in your code.

I tried this same code on my setup and I get the same session_id and same cookie value each time.

I would try to fix your server setup issue but if you can't you can force the session id to be consistent. Do this:

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['SSID']) {
    session_start($_COOKIE['SSID']);
} else {
    session_start();
}
```

Also if the cookie already exists you don't need to create a new one:

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['SSID']) {
    setcookie("SSID", $id);
}
```

Comment: this code will not solve my problem, because the SSID retrieved from the cookie will not be the right one. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes it will because the session_id changing is the problem. The cookie value is set correctly.

Comment: Ok, I will try. I assume that both pieces of code goes in the test1.php right ?

Comment: Yes it replaces the lines where you start the session and where you set the cookie.

Comment: Is this all the code that is running or is there other stuff you aren't showing us?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved this using only session storage but not before changing some parameters in the production server, I dont know which one, sorry.

I really appreciate all your help.